# A possible improvement of witharrows package

Tags: color, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, arrows, witharrows

I was looking at this question  [Please help me solve. i am trying](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609050/please-help-me-solve-i-am-trying) where there is the image below.

[image]

In my comment I have suggested using the `witharrows` package. I don't know this package very well, but using this code fragment (pag. 30 of the documentation) I have an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 tikz-code = {\draw
                       (#1) -- ++(4.5cm,0) |- (#2) ;
?
```

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
[displaystyle,
ygap = 2mm,
ystart = 0mm,
tikz-code = {\draw (#1) -- ++(4.5cm,0) |- (#2) ;
\path (#1) -- (#2)
node[text width = 4.2cm, right, midway] {#3} ;}]
S_n
& = \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}2\cdot\tfrac kn\bigr)
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

The output should be the first line:

[image]

> Is is possible to put `$\cos x =\Re(e^{ix})$` externally and not internally by coloring the entire square arrow with a color of your choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not good at writing equations -- but I think this is what you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}%
[displaystyle,
ygap = 2mm,
ystart = 0mm,
tikz-code = {\draw [red,thick](#1) -- ++(4.5cm,0) |- (#2) ;%<---------new red, thick option
            \path (#1) -- (#2)
            node[text width = 4.2cm, right, midway, xshift=5cm] {#3} ;}]%<-------xshift option
S_n
& = \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}2\cdot\tfrac kn\bigr)  \Arrow {we expand} \\
& = \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}2\cdot\tfrac kn\bigr)
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

**OR**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}%
[displaystyle,
ygap = 2mm,
ystart = 0mm,
tikz-code = {\draw [red,thick,rounded corners](#1) -- ([xshift=2cm]#1) 
            -- node[rectangle, draw, auto = false, fill = gray!50, inner sep = 2pt] {\tiny #3}
            ([xshift=2cm]#2)
            -- (#2);}]
S_n
& = \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}2\cdot\tfrac kn\bigr)  \Arrow {we expand} \\
& = \frac1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}2\cdot\tfrac kn\bigr)
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a good option, as are your other great answers with TikZ. My sincere congratulations to you and a cordial greeting to you and your family. :-) My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano, if answer met your requirement, you may accept it ;-) (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer).  Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry. :-) I know the procedure :-). Truly I am waiting also the complete answer of @F. Pantigny for the correctness (see the comment below his answer). Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You should write `\begin{WithArrows*}%`. Otherwise, the options at the following line are not recognized as options of the environment `{WithArrows*}`: there must be no space between `\begin{WithArrows*}` and the character `[` (and the newline counts as space).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (+1) but I have an error: `! LaTeX Error: Environment WithArrows* undefined. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help....                                                                                          
l.5 \begin{WithArrows*}
                       %
? `

Comment: In your opinion is there a complete answer to my question?

Comment: @Sebastiano: For the LaTeX error, I think that you have not the latest version of `witharrows`. For the complete answer, I will see.

Comment: Yesterday I made the MikTeX updating...and I will wait....Grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.

Comment: Waiting Pantigny..I have given the check mark. :-)